# Highchart - overlapping label should NOT be hidden

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, overlap

Sometimes my points are close together and my highchart is hiding my labels. Is there an option to avoid this (charts are drawn from data that is regularly refreshed)

in the example, point "A TEST" and "B - PLEASE SHOW ME" are close together which results in an overlap. The chart is automatically hiding the label for B, but I want it to show (the chart shouldn't have more than about 3 points so the clutter shouldn't be a problem)

http://jsfiddle.net/4jb4gusj/1/

```
$(function () {


$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {type: 'scatter'},
    title: {text: 'title'},
    subtitle: {text: 'subtitle'},
    xAxis: {
        min: 2,
        max: 5,
        type: 'linear',
        title: {
            text: 'Weight'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Height'
        },
        min: 110,
        max: 170

    },
    legend: {
    Layout : 'vertical'
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },
    plotOptions: {
       scatter: {
           dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.series.name ;
                },
                enabled: true
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {hover: {marker: {enabled: false}}},
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: "A TEST ", data: [[3.91, 140.63]]
            }, {
        name: "B - PLEASE SHOW ME",
        data: [[3.65, 143.68]]
    }, {
        name: "C TEST ",
        data: [[2.69, 172.94]]
    }
     ]
});
```

});

Comment: thanks, sorry - the 'links to jsfiddle without code had me confused for a moment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If overlapping not an issue , use

```
allowOverlap:true,
```

updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4jb4gusj/2/)

Comment: thanks that's it. appreciate the assist. Looks like the library I'm using - dotnet.highstock may not have support for that so I may need to add it

Comment: allowoverlap is available in datalabel, check it

Comment: thanks, it is - unless you're using https://github.com/lisa3907/dotnet.highstock - ammended the source and it's working (now I need to submit the change, but I've made 2 or 3 of them so far).